# Converting int with str into list (trying to print integers as words)

Tags: python, data-conversion

I'm making a deck of cards for a game I created and am running into the problem of renaming my face cards. All cards with values of 11-14 I want to retain their value in-code but show to the user as Jack, Queen, King and Ace (respectively). Using the `str()` and `int()` functions do not work. Using `print().format` doesn't work. And using the match class dictionary doesn't work. I cannot get the mapping to work.

Instead, when I instantiate my shuffled Deck, I get my full deck plus 4 additional face cards (4 Jacks, 4 Queens, 4 Kings, 4 Aces) that were not put through the `random.shuffle()` though I suspect this is because they were not passed through self.cards.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import random

class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit

    def show(self):
        print('{} of {}'.format(self.value, self.suit))
```

---

```
class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        for s in ["Joker"]:
            for v in range(1, 3):
                self.cards.append(Card(v, s))
        for s in ["Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts"]:
            for v in range(2, 15):
                if v is 11:
                    print('{} of {}'.format("Jack", s))
                if v is 12:
                    print('{} of {}'.format("Queen", s))
                if v is 13:
                    print('{} of {}'.format("King", s))
                if v is 14:
                    print('{} of {}'.format("Ace", s))
                self.cards.append(Card(v, s))
    def show(self):
        for c in self.cards:
            c.show()

    def shuffle(self):
        for i in range(len(self.cards)-1, 0, -1):
            random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def draw(self):
        return self.cards.pop()
```

Comment: where do you want to convert this exactly ?

Comment: In the def build(self) method because that is where the deck's list is located (the two ranges), but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: what did you do with str function? give me a sample ...

Comment: I used str() and int() in just about every part in the "def build(self):" method section to no avail. For instance, when I got an error that the replace() method I used needed an integer, I used int() on all values within that section. I also wrapped str() around every value within that section.

Comment: Hey, I'm glad it worked for you. FYI, the best way to mark an answer as accepted or helpful is to click the checkmark next to it and/or click the up arrow to upvote (instead of editing your original post to ID your chosen soln). Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suspected, the Face cards need to be processed in the `Card.show()` method.

```
def show(self):
    if self.value is 11:
        print('Jack of {}'.format(self.suit))
    elif self.value is 12:
        print('Queen of {}'.format(self.suit))
    elif self.value is 13:
        print('King of {}'.format(self.suit))
    elif self.value is 14:
        print('Ace of {}'.format(self.suit))
    else:
        print('{} of {}'.format(self.value, self.suit))
```

Notice that you'll need to use `self.value` when checking whether the Card object is a Face card (Ace, Jack, Queen, King), and `self.suit` to get the Card's suit.

You can also remove all of the checks in the `Deck.build()` method, so that it becomes:

```
def build(self):
    for s in ["Joker"]:
        for v in range(1, 3):
            self.cards.append(Card(v, s))
    for s in ["Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts"]:
        for v in range(2, 15):
            self.cards.append(Card(v, s))
```

Once these changes are made, you will be able to generate a 52-card deck along with 2 additional Jokers. I tested the other Deck methods and all seems to be fine after these changes.

Example usage (python 2.7 print function):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = Deck()
    d.show()
    print "number of cards=", len(d.cards)

    d.shuffle()
    c = d.draw()
    c.show()
    print "number of cards=", len(d.cards)
    d.show()
```

Comment: This works! Beautiful. Thank you so much, Matt P. And I learned something valuable in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

```
if v is 11:
    print('Jack of {}'.format(s))
else if v is 12:
    print('Queen of {}'.format(s))
else if v is 13:
    print('King of {}'.format(s))
else if v is 14:
    print('Ace of {}'.format(s))
```

Change the relevant part to this.

Comment: I tried this with no change. I even changed "else if" to "elif". I think it's a double-problem: I can't convert int to str, and the extra face cards are being appended to the Deck list.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a `__repr__` method. If you add the following method to your Card object, when you call `print(Deck().draw())`, you will get the cards name rather than `<__main__.Card object at 0x00000000036359E8>`.

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '{} of {}'.format(self.value, self.suit)
```

Is this what you were looking for?